# route does not render inside the Router tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi guys so I have this issue with my code while learning about Routes and cannot seem to find the answer. My page does not render at some point, as I will explain below.

This is the index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./app/App";
import { store } from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and this is the app.js

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import About from "../components/About";
import SignUp from "../components/SignUp";
import Articles from "../components/Articles";
import Article from "../components/Article";
import Categories from "../components/Categories";
import Author from "../components/Author";
import Profile from "../components/Profile";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./App.css";


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main>
      
      </main>
      <Footer />
  </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So far my app is rendering, BUT...
when I want to do this:

```
<Router>
      <Header />
      <main>
            <Route path='/about'>
            <About />
            </Route>
      </main>
      <Footer />
  </Router>
```

then **everything disappears**. It does the same in the development and production build.

This is the first time I'm using Router and I am doing this project following a video tutorial and some instructions. Basically, I should be doing everything right, right?

My package.json looks like this :

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-markdown": "^6.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
```

What I mean by disappearing is that the page does not render anything at all:

**without route element**

[image: without route element]

**with the route element**

[image: with the route element]

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

- `Route` components ***must*** be rendered by a `Routes` component.
- Routed content ***must*** be rendered by the `Route` component's `element` prop as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

## Solution

Wrap the `Route` with the `Routes` component and render the `About` component on the `element` prop.

```
<Router>
  <Header />
  <main>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
  </main>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

Comment: Ok, so I am using react-router-dom: 6.3 and in the tutorial, they were using 5.2. Your advice did the work partially, as the rest of the code is kind of mixed up. Going forward, should I try to understand how router-dom 5.2 works or just get to know how to use 6.3? (I am learning through BootCamp, not using it at work at the moment). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @sergiuR The component APIs changed significantly between v5 and v6, so without a strong base level of knowledge in routing/navigation you may want to stick to using v5 with the coding examples you are working with until you've grasped all the concepts. That said, many v5 routing concepts are obsolete in v6, so perhaps it would just save you some time in the long run to jump into v6 and learn the current ways, which may be easier because you won't have to learn things twice, or worse, unlearn the v5 APIs that are no longer relevant. Being familiar with both can't hurt either though.

Comment: @sergiuR Sorry, that was a lot of text to basically say it's up to you which suites your needs better right now, and for the long term.